# phalcon extends volt with variable, Any other way to make that work

Tags: phalcon, extends, volt

```
{% extends "../../../views/"{{variable}}"/templates/one-column.volt" %}
```

or

```
{% extends "../../../views/"~variable~"/templates/one-column.volt" %}
```

or any other way to make that work.

how to make it work like above. anyone can help me?
framework phalcon

Answer (score 0):

If you are using variable inside the extend or include you have to omit the template extension. In your case it is **.volt**.

**Try like this:**

```
{% extends "../../../views/"~ variable ~"/templates/one-column" %}
```

**Another example:**

```
// When using variable inside the include
{% set folderVar = 'partials' %}
{% include "_layouts/"~ folderVar ~"/header" %}

// Without using variable
{% include "_layouts/partials/header.phtml" %}
```

Explanation of this behaviour: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#include